# cl.exe clashes on VS2015 x64 x86 Cross Tools Command Prompt with Threadripper 1950X and 3200Mhz memory

Tags: boost, build

I've frequently met clashes of cl.exe when I'm trying to build boost c++ library with 'VS2015 x64 x86 cross tools command prompt'.
Below is my environment.

--

OS : Windows 10 Pro 64bit

CPU : AMD Threadripper 1950X

Memory : Corsair's 3200MHz (CMR16GX4M2C3200C16)

M/B : MSI X399 SLI PLUS(BIOS ver A.20)

--

cl.exe frequently clashes in building process. It doesn't occur in x64 native command prompt.

Is it a bug ?

Comment: And, I've met the blue screen with 'MEMORY_MANAGEMENT' error when I build 32bit boost libraries in 'VS2015 x64 Native Command Prompt'.

Comment: this is the build command i used. b2 toolset=msvc-14.0 address-model=32 link=shared,static --build-type=complete --stagedir=stage/work -j 32